# FineUploader: Possible to upload to different locations based on file type?

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload, amazon-s3, fine-uploader

Happy Friday!

I was curious if the following was possible:

I'd like to be able to upload media to different locations based on its file type. I really appreciate that [Fine Uploader](http://fineuploader.com/) can upload directly to Amazon S3, but I don't want everything to go straight to S3. I'm using WordPress and need to generate different image sizes for uploaded media, so I'd like to upload images to my server for processing and then over to S3 ( via [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/) ). Any other media ( audio, video, etc ) I'd like to upload to S3. What do you think? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you ok have two separate Fine Uploader instances?  This is what would be required.  Essentially, you would have to setup a button tied to a traditional endpoint Fine Uploader, and another tied to a Fine Uploader S3 instance.  The buttons could have specific validation restrictions tied to them to prevent users from accidentally submitting an image file to the S3 uploader.

Another option is to provide your own file input element, check the submitted files, and then pass the appropriate file(s) to the appropriate Fine Uploader instance via Fine Uploader's API ([addBlobs](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addBlobs) or [addFiles](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#addFiles)).

Another possibility: just allow your users to upload all files to S3, and pull the each image file back down to your server (temporarily) after they have reached the bucket, modify it, and send it back to S3.

Note that I am working on a feature for Fine Uploader 4.4 that will allow you to specify images sizes via options, and Fine Uploader will scale the images and send each scaled image separately to whatever endpoint you choose.  See [issue #1061 for details/progress updates](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1061).

Comment: That's what I was thinking myself, I didn't know if there was any sort of built in validation that could encompass one instance. Thanks for the help!